# Xamarin Forms - how to add background image to a content page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to assign Background Image to my content designed in `xaml`. I have tried different approaches but it is not showing me background image. Here is the code I have written:

**Content Page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Demo.Welcome"
             BackgroundImage="bg1.jpg">

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="25" Padding="0" x:Name="stackLayoutMain">
      <Label FontSize="40" Text="WelCome Page" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
      <Entry Placeholder="Activation Key" WidthRequest="200" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextChanged="entryActivationTextChanged" x:Name="entryActivationKey" Keyboard="Numeric" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Entry>
      <Button
        x:Name="buttonActivate"
        BackgroundColor="#fff"
        Text="Activate"
        WidthRequest="100"
        HeightRequest="50"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        TextColor="#377CC1"
        IsVisible="False"
        Clicked="buttonActivateClicked" >
      </Button>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

`bg1.jpg` is image in my portable project which i want to set as a background and I have set property

- `Build Action = "Content"` and
- `Copy to Output Directory = "Copy Always"`

And Below is the directory structure of my project.

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: 1. Do you have the build action of your image as "Embedded Resource" ? 
2. It does not work for both platforms ? 
3. Try to use an image for the web to see if it works or not.

Comment: How do you size it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My suggestion is to put images to folder:

for **Android** `Resources/drawable`

for **iOS** `Resources`

Comment: Depending on screen size you may need to use more than just drawable folder

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<string> objEmpCollections = new List<string>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.Title = "V V I P's";
        //this.BackgroundColor = Color.Maroon;
        this.BackgroundImage = "EmpMgmtPCL.Images.NPO-Events-bg.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI the question demonstrated they were using XAML so the answer should in that way.