# embedded image in Xamarin Forms using c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Guys Im having a little trouble trying to make an image the background for a certain page. Im trying to do it via the embedded method mentioned here:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images 
.For some reason when I run the app, it crashes. I think something went wrong at 'BackgroundImage =' line cause I kinda guessed when I did that. When I comment out that line, the app loads fine, just without the background image. I used build action = content and copy to output directory as settings...

```
public class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    Entry emailBox = new Entry();
    Entry passwordBox = new Entry();
    Button createAccount = new Button();
    Button forgotPassword = new Button();
    StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
    Image embeddedImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Charity.Properties.hands-426x640.jpg") };

    public LoginPage()
    {
        Title = "Login";
        BackgroundColor = Color.LightPink;
        BackgroundImage = "Charity.Properties.hands-426x640.jpg";

        emailBox.Placeholder = "email";
        emailBox.BackgroundColor = Color.LightPink;
        emailBox.PlaceholderColor = Color.HotPink;

        passwordBox.Placeholder = "password";
        passwordBox.BackgroundColor = Color.LightPink;
        passwordBox.PlaceholderColor = Color.HotPink;
        passwordBox.IsPassword = true;

        createAccount.Text = "create an account";
        createAccount.TextColor = Color.HotPink;
        createAccount.Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Medium);
        createAccount.BorderWidth = 0;
        createAccount.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        createAccount.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

        forgotPassword.Text = "recover password";
        forgotPassword.TextColor = Color.HotPink;
        forgotPassword.Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Medium);
        forgotPassword.BorderWidth = 0;
        forgotPassword.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        forgotPassword.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

        layout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
        layout.BackgroundColor = Color.LightPink;

        layout.Children.Add(emailBox);
        layout.Children.Add(passwordBox);
        layout.Children.Add(createAccount);
        layout.Children.Add(forgotPassword);

        Content = layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the path you used for the embedded image and then look at the path you used for the background. Hint hint.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949707/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-background-image-to-a-content-page

Comment: @Nkosi I tried to change it to this BackgroundImage = "Charity.Properties.hands-426x640.jpg"; but the app still crashes when it runs. That link is in xaml right ? Ive yet to learn xaml, I've  only learnt c# so far..

Comment: In the Droid project, I have theBuild Action for my image set to AndroidResource.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39175/contentpage-backgroundimage-issue

Comment: Also get rid of the hyphen in the file name. That was a problem for me.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, after much trial and error, I found out that I had not included the image in the iOS resources folder. Now it works fine :)

Comment: @dev1998 Thanks, after much trial and error, I found out that I had not included the image in the iOS resources folder. Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, after much trial and error I only needed to add the image to both .Droid(drawable) and .iOS(resources) folders. I had not added it to the iOS folder previously, hence it kept crashing when I ran on an iOS simulator.

```
    Image image = new Image();

    public LoginPage()
    {
        Title = "Login"; 
        BackgroundImage = "hands426x640.jpg";}
```

Comment: You realize that was suggested in the link I provided. Right? Any how I am glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Nkosi haha yep, thats where I got the idea to try :) Thanks man!