# How to add background image to grid layout in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have four  rows and two columns.I need to display the background  image to full grid.Please provide me solution.I had referred this creating background image in content page link:[Xamarin Forms - how to add background image to a content page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949707/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-background-image-to-a-content-page)
.But how to set background image to grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Image to the first row and column, set ColumnSpan and RowSpan to cover your entire grid and set the Aspect to AdjustFit.

Then you add the other items you want to add to the grid.

A grid cell can hold more than just one element, however keep in mind that the last item in a cell will end up on top of the items having been added earlier.

For example:

```
<Grid>
    <Image>
    <Button>
</Grid>
```

The button is the last item in the order, so it will become the topmost item and be clickable. If you had the button first and the image last, the image would cover the button, which therefore would not be clickable.

Comment: Due to resolution problems i cant use absolute layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some `AbsoluteLayout` trickery here:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
<Image  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1.0, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" InputTransparent="true" Source="Your_Image" Aspect="AspectFill" />
<!--Your Grid Here-->
<Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1.0, 1.0" />
<AbsoluteLayout>
```

See to it that you place the image first in absolute layout so that it goes in the back,
and set its input transparent so it does not take any click events.